Current prices of tokens to be exchanged with Pancakeswap
I get the list of pools with Pancakeswap Exchange V3 Subgraph API, but the price information in the pool information does not match the price on the site. Also, as the amount increases, the price on the site changes. How can I pull or calculate the current price on the site? A sample c# code would be great.
In the Pancakeswap Exchange V3 Subgraph API, I thought that the token0price and token1price values in the pools list are the price of a token0 in token1 and vice versa, but the price on the site does not match the price in the API. I couldn't find any documentation for the Subgraph API, so I couldn't figure out how to use it.

Data may not be stored in order in the database.  To get the latest price sort by DateTime Descending and then use the first price.

I don't think it has anything to do with the database. I think token0Price and token1Price are the values of the last swap transaction. I want to make a software where I can display the prices of the tokens that I can buy for USDT via Pancakeswap. I wanted to do it over the BSC network, but I couldn't find any information about how to do this with SmartRouterV3. A c# example would be great.
